# Oracle group by clause using nested function in the select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I need to find the available seats of a flight. ie: subtract the number of bookings made for a flight from the capacity of the plane assigned to that flight. I have a query working, but it is only showing the 'available seats' column.  I want to show the 'flight number' column but I get the "not a single-group group function" etc errors when I try to add the column in to display.  I think I need to join the tables to make the select statement allow me to print the flight_number column, but I'm not sure how to do that. Could someone point me in the right direction.  Thanks a lot.

```
select sum(p.capacity - (count(b.passenger_id))) as available_seats from booking b, PLANES p
where b.date_of_flight = '16-Oct-2014' and depart_city = 'Sydney' and arrival_city = 'Perth'
and flight_number in (select flight_number from scheduled_flights sf 
                      where sf.airplane_serial = p.airplane_serial
                      and b.date_of_flight = sf.date_of_flight
                      )
group by p.capacity 
;
```

This is the result:

```
      available_seats
1       237
```

which is correct, but I would like:

```
     flight_number  available_seats
1      TF81              237
```

Thanks for helping :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this?

```
select flight_number, p.capacity - count(b.passenger_id) as available_seats 
 from booking b, PLANES p, scheduled_flights sf
where b.date_of_flight = '16-Oct-2014' and depart_city = 'Sydney' and arrival_city = 'Perth'
  and flight_number = sf.flight_number
  and sf.airplane_serial = p.airplane_serial
  and b.date_of_flight = sf.date_of_flight
group by flight_number, p.capacity;
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes I tried that but I get the "not a single-group function" error

Comment: @user3514228, It's strange. Have you noticed a "flight_number" in a GROUP BY in my version?

Comment: sorry, i misread your answer as I was reading it on my phone. Thank you so much! that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another aggregate function on flight_number like "max(flight_number)" in SELECT clause. It won't change your logic and you shouldn't get this error any more.